# Optimize assigning data to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a ObservableCollection filling a listbox representing a calendar.

```
private ObservableCollection<DateItem> _DateList = new ObservableCollection<DateItem>();
public ObservableCollection<DateItem> DateList { get { return _DateList; } }
```

When the user requests the next month I get the already parsed month from a seperate class and assign them to my ObservableCollection like so:

```
// clear DateList first
DateList.Clear();
// set month
foreach (DateItem item in parsemonth.GetNextMonth())
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => DateList.Add(item));
```

Everything works fine. But clearing the data and add the new data takes almost a second in the view. I wonder if this can be optimized so that I can reduce the time that my calendar shows no data.

EDIT: this only happens on an actual device (Lumia 920), on the emulator there isnt such delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large collection, the problem may be the fact that you're sending out an event for each item that gets added.  Since you're always clearing the collection, you could create a version of ObservableCollection that disables updates while adding items:

```
/// <summary>
/// An observable collection that supports batch changes without sending CollectionChanged
/// notifications for each individual modification
/// </summary>
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// While true, CollectionChanged notifications will not be sent.
    /// When set to false, a NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset will be sent.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsBatchModeActive
    {
        get { return _isBatchModeActive; }
        set
        {
            _isBatchModeActive = value;

            if (_isBatchModeActive == false)
            {
                OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _isBatchModeActive;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsBatchModeActive)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateList.IsBatchModeActive = true;  // Disables collection change events
DateList.Clear();

foreach (DateItem item in parsemonth.GetNextMonth())
    DateList.Add(item);

DateList.IsBatchModeActive = false;  // Sends a collection changed event of Reset and re-enables collection changed events
```

Comment: Interesting! Can I manually sent a CollectionChanged event after all items have been added, so that the view updates?

Comment: When you set IsBatchModeActive to false then the collectionchanged event will get sent.  I'll add a usage section to my answer.

Comment: Seems to be a bit faster, not much but still. Thank you!

Comment: Mm after testing a bit more, it seems that this only works in the emulator. On the device the view is still updated even if the DateList.IsBatchModeActive is true all the time...

Comment: Are you still dispatching the Add calls?

Comment: Heh.  So did it help?

Comment: The time between clearing and adding new elements in the view is indeed gone now. But because adding the elements still takes time the view only reacts after a second. So in terms of speed, it remained the same.